# How to run nodeJS tests with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am learning about Jenkins CI and using pipeline to stage my jobs. I've ran into a halt where my tests aren't running. Please take a look at my "Jenkins Images" link. As you can see its stuck in the `--coverage` table. Typically, if i were to run my tests on my local machine, i would have to enter `w`command to get node to run all tests; however, i don't think it would be the same in a jenkins setting

[Jenkins Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSaqP.png)

Jenkinsfile

```
def gv

pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {nodejs "node"}
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'VERSION', choices: ['1.1.0', '1.2.0', '1.3.0'], description: '')
        booleanParam(name: 'executeTests', defaultValue: true, description: '')
    }
    stages {
        stage("init") {
            steps {
                script {
                   gv = load "script.groovy"
                   CODE_CHANGES = gv.getGitChanges()
                }
            }
        }
        stage("build frontend") {
            steps {
                dir("client") {
                    sh 'npm install'
                    echo 'building client'
                }
            }
        }
        stage("build backend") {
            steps {
                dir("server") {
                    sh 'npm install'
                    echo 'building server...'
                }
            }
        }
        stage("test") {
            when {
                expression {
                    script {
                        env.BRANCH_NAME.toString().equals('feature-jenkins') && CODE_CHANGES == false
                    }
                }
            }
            steps {
                dir("/client") {
                    sh 'npm test'
                    echo 'testing application'
                }
            }
        }
        stage("deploy") {
            steps {
                script {
                    gv.deployApp()
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Set the env var CI=true then Jest won't run in interactive mode.

Comment: ohhh great that worked! thank you!